# Retrieve caching list In Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-3

I am using Spring3.1 in standalone Env.

I am trying to cache my entries.
So in 3.1 I can use @Cacheable this way:

```
@Cacheable("client")
@Override
public ClientDTO getClientByLogin(String login) throws FixException
{
    ClientDTO client = null;
    try
    {
        client = (ClientDTO) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_CLIENT_BY_LOGIN_STATEMENT, new Object[]
        { login }, new ClientDTO());
    }
    catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e)
    {
        log.error("Client login not exist in database. login=" + login);
    }

    if (client == null)
    {
        throw new FixException("Return null from DB when executing getClientByLogin(), login=" + login);
    }
    return client;
}
```

now each time i invoke getClient it will look first in it's cache respositry.

If I want to retrieve the caching list in order to iterate on it. How i do it?

thanks.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
private ClientDTO getClientDTOByClientId(Integer clientId)
{
    ClientDTO clientDTO = null;
    Cache clientCache = null;
    try
    {
        clientCache = ehCacheCacheManager.getCache("client");
        clientDTO = null;
        if (clientCache != null)
        {
            clientDTO = (ClientDTO) clientCache.get(clientId);
        }
        else
        {
            log.error("clientCache is null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Couldnt retrieve client from cache. clientId=" + clientId);
    }
    return clientDTO;
}
```

Comment: You said you wanted to get the list of all cached objects, yet you here just fetch a single object...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retrieve the cached object, then the following code should work

```
public ClientDTO  getCachedClient() {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("client");
        Object cachedObject = null;
        Object nativeCache = cache.getNativeCache();
        if (nativeCache instanceof net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache) {
            net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache ehCache = (net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache) nativeCache;
            List<Object> keys = ehCache.getKeys();

            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                for (Object key : keys) {
                    Element element = ehCache.get(key);
                    if (element != null) {

                        cachedObject = element.getObjectValue();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (ClientDTO)cachedObject;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such way in Spring Cache to iterate on caching list. If you want to iterate over collection of ClientDTO you need to put it into the cache:

```
@Cacheable(value="client", key="all")
@Override
public List<ClientDTO> getAll() throws FixException  {
  List<ClientDTO> clients = null;
  try {
    clients = ....; // fetch all objects
  } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
    //
  }

  if (clients == null) {
    //
  }
  return clients;
}
```

In such case each time you modify client object you should invalidate the list.

Comment: It does something but it doesn't use Spring Cache correctly. How the method getClientDTOByClientId is connected with getClientByLogin? It doesn't return list of all clients but only one that is in cache.

Comment: I do want only the ones in the cache.

Comment: Yes.. but how could I iterate on it?? like with for each

Comment: Using only Spring Cache it is not possible because you cannot get list of all keys stored in cache, so you don't know which objects may be fetch. If you know a range of client ids you may try this: for(int clientId=MIN_ID; clientId < MAX_ID; clientId++) { getClientDTOByClientId(clientId);}. This makes sense only if the range of ID is small and you know that most of the objects are in cache.